# partial derivative in an exat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have to determinate if this equation is an exact differential equation,

[image]

but I don't now how get the partial derivative respect X & Y, I am confuse, please help me step by step I would aprecciate it, thanks.

I have this:

[image]
I got this, I don't know if this is correct I think it doesn't, so I would aprecciate if you let me know the mistakes, please if you can help me do it step by step.

Comment: Please document your efforts. The first parenthesis is derived by y, the second by x. They should be equal.

Comment: I know the first parenthesis is respect to y and the second is respect to x, but when I derive the result I get respect to Y & X are different, so I think I am doing something wrong. I want to know what is the correct  partial derivative respect to y & x, please if you can help me, do it step by step.

Comment: Please write down what you get, one can not help without seeing your problem.

Comment: I wrote down, please tell me if what I get is ok.

Answer (score 0):

In the first derivative, you have to apply both the product rule and the chain rule of differentiation correctly. It is not correct to just cancel $y$.

The second term of the difference is of the form
$$
f(x,y)·g(h(x,y))
$$
Its $y$-derivative has thus the form
$$
f_y(x,y)·g(h(x,y))+f(x,y)·g'(h(x,y))·h_y(x,y)
$$